# Problem in understanding pointer to an Object set to NULL

Tags: c++, class

Can any one explain what does it mean by making an pointer to an object to NULL?

When we assign ptr to an object to NULL, how can we still access the member function?

```
class A
{
public:
    void print()
    {
        cout<<"Hello";
    }
}

int main()
{
    A * a;
    A* b = NULL;

    a->print();
    b->print();
}
```

**EDIT:**
Will the program crash?
http://ideone.com/DudZ6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pointer is used for accessing the members of that object. If your function(s) don't need to access any members and are not virtual, they actually don't use the object. The code is still strictly speaking invalid, but it won't crash.

If you replace the contents with printing the "this" pointer, it'll still work as you're not dereferencing it.

```
struct X { 
    void print() { 
        cout << "this pointer is " << this << endl; 
    } 
};

int main() {
    X *x;
    x->print(); // will print whatever was on the stack, ie, random garbage
    X *t = NULL;
    t->print(); // will print a null pointer
}
```

If you add one member variable and print that, or make the function virtual (so it will have to be looked up through the object itself) it will crash.

```
struct X { 
    virtual void print() { 
        cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
    } 
};

struct X2 { 
    int y;
    void print() { 
        cout << "y is " << y << endl; 
    } 
};

int main() {
    X *x = NULL;
    x->print(); // will crash on null pointer dereference
    X2 *x2 = NULL;
    x2->print(); // will crash on null pointer dereference
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's not.  This answer just describes what happens in one particular implementation.  The behavior is undefined, and other implementations may do something different.

Comment: @dascandy can you please add an example for your second point regarding this pointer. Thank you for you reply. Will mark it accepted as soon as time limit finishes.

Comment: @James, agree, adding one of "usually", "very often", "almost always", "couldn't imagine anything else" should be more precise.

Comment: From the question "how can we still access the member function?" implies empirical observation on some particular platform... this answer does explain how it's possible for the code to execute *if* the compiler basically ignores the value of the pointer until accessing member data or the virtual dispatch pointer. But, "strictly speaking invalid, but it won't crash" is promising too much... even if the non-crashing behaviour has been observed on that particular platform, there's nothing in the Standard guaranteeing it will do the same even if the same executable is reexecuted.

Comment: @Als It was a long time ago, so it could have changed, but the
GreenHills compiler used to crash on it.  And you're not really claiming
that dereferencing a null pointer is not undefined behavior, are you?
It's the very example of undefined behavior used in §1.9.

Comment: @Tony: My bad, I added the quote from the standard to James's, answer for more completeness.

Answer (score 5):

You can't.  Any attempt to dereference the pointer (any application of
the `*` or `->` operator to it) is undefined behavior, and may do
anything.  Most of the time, of course, you'll only crash if the
code actually needs data from the object (including internal data like a
`vptr`); otherwise, the code will seem to work.  But that's just one of
the possible undefined behaviors; I've actually used a compiler where
your small program would crash.

---

As per **C++ Standard**:

***1.9 Program execution

4:***

*Certain other operations are described in this International Standard as undefined (**for example, the effect of dereferencing the null pointer**). [Note: this International Standard imposes no requirements on the behavior of programs that contain undefined behavior. ]*

So strictly, speaking the behavior is undefined, As many have pointed out in comments section just because it works on a particular platform does not make it legal.

**So the as per the C++ standard the behavior of the code snippet is Undefined Behavior.**

Comment: I've worked in an environment where I had an object at address 0x0. Null pointers definitely wouldn't crash there.

Comment: @James Kanze: +1, I took the liberty to add the Standard quote to your answer for completeness, I hope that is fine, if not feel free to revert it back.

Comment: @dascandy As has already been pointed out, it's undefined behavior.  I've worked in several environments where writing through a null pointer would modify critical data in the OS.  But no C or C++ object can be at the same address; if the system uses the physical address 0 for a C or C++, it must use some other bit pattern for the null pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You can't,

```
   A* b = NULL;
 b->print();
```

this is *undefined bahvior* and could make your program crash with a [segmentation fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) (depending on the definition of your `print` method).

Generally speaking, assigning NULL to a pointer is used to give the pointer a value that means "this pointer is not set, do not use it". Take this code:

```
void function() {
   int* p;
   int* q = NULL:
   ... 
}
```

when the function is called, `p` and `q` are allocated on the stack; due to the way compiler works, `p` is left unassigned, that means that it gets the value that it is found on the stack at the moment of calling the function; this is a random value that usually has not much to do with your program.

Now, the fact that `p` has got a value could lead you into thinking that this value is "correct", so you use it; but, it is not (because it is random, due to not initializing the pointer), so you also get a crash or some kind of unexpected behavior.

In the case of `q`, the fact of assigning `NULL` to it allows you to tell that it has no usable value. So, you don't reference it:

```
 if (q != NULL) {
     q->....
 }
```

The idiom above does not work for `p`, so you have no way to tell whether it is ok.

In the end: *always* initialize your variable; in the case of pointers, if you do not have a vlaue to assign, assign NULL, so you know that pointer should not be dereferenced.

Comment: @Als It depends on the implementation.  It's undefined behavior, and I've used compilers where it would crash.  The fact that some compilers let you get away with it doesn't make it legal.